# Merging partitions in the installation process

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I want to merge two partitions without losing my data but I don't have gParted since I'm in the middle of the Ubuntu installation process on a VM(VirtualBox on Macbook Air). [image: Some other type of installation]

As you can see by my screenshot, I want to merge `/dev/sda1` and `dev/sda6`. I also have a Ubuntu .iso on a USB drive. Yet I have all this information and I'm very confused so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I'm using GParted now after I clicked `Try Install`. This is my partition:

[image: partition table in GParted]

Edit: I typed the `top` command in the terminal and I got this:

[image: top command]

Comment: Since you're installing, simply hit the Back button and re-do your partition setup.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

You cannot, without `gparted` (or equivalent) move the partitions around so that the to-be-merged partitions are adjacent on the disk.

You cannot, halfway through an install, easily shuffle this disk partitions and get everything to work on the first try. This way lies madness.

Comment: So I should just reinstall Ubuntu and then use Gparted?

Comment: No. Reinstall Ubuntu and set the partitions how you want during the installation. No need for GParted afterwards.

Comment: But he wants to keep the data.

Answer (score 0):

At this point you can't say to the installer tool (or any partitioning tool I'm aware of) "merge these 2 partitions". I assume your /dev/sda1 is an existing partition with data on it as you would not use 7GB on a fresh install, and /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 have not been formatted yet.

Here is what I would do to move forward and have data you don't want to lose on /dev/sda1.

- Stop the installation process
- Start gparted (a GUI partition editor) and delete /dev/sda5 (the swap partition)
- Using gparted, expand /dev/sda1 to the max it will allow you
- If you have data on /dev/sda6 (once again, I think it is not formatted yet based on the screenshot): open Files to get access to it, and copy data over to /dev/sda1 using the Files tool
- If you run out of space on /dev/sda1, you can start gparted to shrink /dev/sda6 and grow /dev/sda1 as files get copied over
- using Files, create a new folder in the /dev/sda1 partition, and move everything in there
- when you are done, start gparted and delete /dev/sda6
- after /dev/sda6 is deleted, grow /dev/sda1 to the size you want (I'd say 18G will do in this case) using gparted once more
- close gparted, restart the installation, and do a full install using /dev/sda1 as /
- during the installation process you can create your swap partition, which will now become /dev/sda2

After installing and first boot, you can move the files you wanted to keep from the folder you create to your home directory. You will find the folder in the root of the filesystem. E.g. if you named the folder "all_my_data" the location will be "/all_my_data".

And that's it.

At no point in time you should format/delete /dev/sda1 !!!

Comment: I stopped the installation and it looks like `dev/sda6` wasn't saved. Also, I can't delete `dev/sda5`, as shown in the second picture.

Comment: That is because the swap partition is active. Click "swapoff" to disable and you then should be able to delete it. Make sure you delete the "extended" partition as well. As sda6 is already gone, you can just use gparted to resize /dev/sda1 and go on from there.